# Getting multiple regression metrics at once

Tags: apache-spark

I'm working with the ML package for regression purposes and I get good results on my data.
I'm now trying to get multiple metrics at once, as right now, I'm doing what is suggested by the examples here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-classification-regression.html

Basically the code in the examples is this:

```
val  evaluator  =  new  RegressionEvaluator()
  .setLabelCol("label")
  .setPredictionCol("prediction")
  .setMetricName("rmse")
val  rmse  =  evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
```

This gives me the RMSE for my test data which is fine, but I'm also interested in MSE, MAE, MAPE, R² and Q²
I thus looked at the documentation here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/evaluation/RegressionEvaluator.html#metricName%28%29

where I see that I can get RMSE, MSE, MAE and R² but it does not appear that I can get them computed all at once, going over the data rows only once and not 5 times as the example code would suggest it is needed to do so.

How can I achieve that single pass computation?

Then, there are MAPE and Q² missing, how can I get those computed as well, ideally while computing the 4 others?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for `RegressionEvaluator`, I discovered that it is implemented by creating a `RegressionMetrics` object which computes all statistics at once via the use of a `MultivariateStatisticalSummary`

Now, looking further at the documentation, I was able to understand that Q² is just R² on the validation set, so the original code got me covered.

But for MAPE, the two terms given to `MultivariateStatisticalSummary` were not enough, so I had to add a new one like this:

```
if (observation != 0)
  math.abs(observation - prediction) / observation
else
  0
```

And then MAPE is just this:

```
def meanAbsolutePercentageError: Double = {
  summary.mean(2)
}
```

So now I have all the metrics that I need and because it uses `MultivariateStatisticalSummary`, I'm confident that the dataset is only processed once.